# Microk8s pod no internet

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, microk8s

A microk8s is installed on Ubuntu 20.04. I did `microk8s enable dns`. Although the server has internet, I do not have access to the internet through the pods. What should I look for, what is the solution?